# Android studio: Cant get App to install on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

So up until today everything was working and after doing some trouble shooting on why my app's code was no longer updating, I uninstalled it from the emulator. Now when I go to run it again, it no longer launches or even displays as existing in my emulator. How do I get it to install on the emulator (again) so that I can continue to develop it further? Thanks guys

The Run Logs: Worked before, nothing unusally here.

```
C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd x86-L
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

Strange thing is that when I read through the Android Monitor it appears to be building the app each time I launch it. but it wont launch/display/install it. not sure how to put it into words sadly.

Any and all suggestions on this matter are welcome. Id love to be able to try different ways to make this work.

Comment: Do you receive any error message or info in Run tab OR any specific Log?

Comment: nope. The only error logs i recieve have been the same ones since i started abot a week ago. Ill edit the main

Comment: have you tried `adb install {file.apk}` on the commandline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the K3b's way of using ADB an a apk file to manually install the app worked. Missing some core functionality by doing this way since some features dont work now  but its a start at least.

```
adb install {file.apk}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your avd memory is greater than your haxm memory. Set avd memory equal or less than haxm memory. For example if haxm memory is 512mb. Set avd memory equal or less than 512mb.

Comment: ok, so I fixed that. But it still wont install my app. Curently trying to follow k3b's idea

Comment: Remove your existing avd and create it again.

Comment: still not working unfortuanetly. Im currently working on trying to create an adb to force install it

Comment: Ok. Last try. Try to update your sdk tools. And always be sure of what changes you do to the working code. So you can rollback changes easily.

Comment: still didnt work but you did manage to make the emulator run smoother so thank you for that

Comment: Welcome. Actually i have never faced such error.  just trying to solve all my known avds bugs. :)